# python convert list to string with newlines

Tags: python

Mostly likely there is some really stupid mistake, however i'm completely stuck on this and not getting what is wrong:

Trying to convert a list to string with newlines for each list element:

```
        meta_temp = ['name: {}; content: {};'.format(el['name'], el['content']) for el in self.meta]
        for hop in meta_temp:
            print(hop)

        self.meta = '\n'.join(map(str, meta_temp))

        for op in self.meta:
            print(op)
```

list `meta_temp` consists of the str objects and `for hop in meta_temp: print(hop)` shows the correct representation -

```
name: generator; content: zmvc; 
name: viewport; content: width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0;
```

and so on.

However, after trying to convert to a string `'\n'.join(map(str, meta_temp))`, **i'm getting the string with newlines after each character**, like (`for op in self.meta: print(op)`):

```
n
a
m
e
:
```

tried:

```
'\n'.join(map(str, meta_temp))
'\n'.join(meta_temp)
''.join(map(str + '\n', meta_temp))
'\n'.join(el for el in meta_temp))
```

Using **python 3.5**

looked into different sources and google it... what am i doing wrong here?
Understand that most likely i'm just blind and missing some small thing. If you minus - please point me on the mistake.

Comment: use `print(self.meta)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self.meta` is a string. Trying to iterate it with `for op in self.meta` and print elements will print one charater at a time. Just print it using `print(self.meta)` and you'll see the newline separated string printing correctly.

Comment: indeed! so blind, i knew it:D sorry, that happens sometimes.